# How can I use the compare_mean() function?

Tags: r

I need to use the compare_mean() and stat_compare_means() functions. These are the libraries I'm using

- `library(ggplot2)`
- `library(magrittr)`
- `library(ggpubr)`

`data("ToothGrowth)`

When I try to use the compare_means I get this error:
    compare_means(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```

Not sure whether the problem relies on the fact that I've rlang_0.3.4.

I've looked around for possible solution with no luck!

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.6

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.2   bindrcpp_0.2  ggpubr_0.2    magrittr_1.5  ggplot2_3.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       tidyr_0.6.3      withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.0 grid_3.3.3       plyr_1.8.4      
 [7] R6_2.2.2         gtable_0.2.0     scales_1.0.0     rlang_0.3.4      lazyeval_0.2.0   tools_3.3.3     
[13] glue_1.3.1       munsell_0.5.0    pkgconfig_2.0.1  colorspace_1.3-2 bindr_0.1        tibble_1.3.3
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`? I have `rlang` version 0.4.0 here and your code ran fine for me, so I don't think it's that your `rlang` version is too new, but it may have to do with the version of one of the other packages you have installed, so `sessionInfo()` could be informative.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've included the output in my question

Comment: Hmm... it looks like I have different versions than you for pretty much all packages, so hard for me to investigate. Have you tried updating your R packages? You can update all your packages using `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

I solve my issue by updating R release to R 3.6.3.